# Spring boot security using multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with different AuthenticationProviders

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to achieve different authentications based on certain http requests, but it appears no matter what the requests are they use the wrong authentications. More specifically, for any ***manage*** endpoint, I want to use only authentication A and for any ***internal*** or ***api*** endpoints I want to use only authentication B.

For example, with the current code, if I send an invalid authentication/user for manage, it will first try to use Authenication A, then fails, and then tries to use authentication B (which is should not).

For manage:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigA extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/manage/**")
                .authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { 

        auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) {

                //do authentication A
            }
        });   
    }
}
```

For api and internal:

```
@Order(2)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigB extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                        "/internal/**",
                        "/api/**")
                .authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {

                @Override
                public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) {

                    //do authentication B
                }
            });   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `configureGlobal` does...

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not sure, I thought it could be used to set the authentication provider for each config...I'm new to spring security and don't fully understand everything...

Comment: No you cannot as the name implies it sets the global authentication provider. If you want to set the "local" one override the `configure(AuthenticvationManagerBuilder)` method.

Comment: I've made both my classes override *configure(AuthenticvationManagerBuilder)* now instead of configureGlobal, but that still doesn't work; now my manage requests are using Authentication B only.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out Mr Nooby Noob?  I'm about to start down the same road, and had done exactly that and only one of the authentications is happening.